# Having a trouble with add-in which works both in Excel and Word and has specific API requirements for both apps

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-2016, office-store

Our Excel-based add-in was recently upgraded to work with both Excel and Word. Initially, we created a separate add-in for Word, but our submission was rejected and we were asked to combine both submissions into a single one:

> This add-in appears to be a duplicate of your Excel add-in already
>   submitted to AppSource. Duplicate add-ins are not permitted on
>   AppSource. Please combine support for all clients required in one
>   add-in submission.

We did that but immediately faced another issue. Our add-in has a dependency on WordApi 1.3 and ExcelApi 1.7. Unfortunately, there is no way to put both requirements together in the same add-in. It makes a list of supported hosts empty because none of them obviously support both APIs. So we made a submission without those requirements set in the manifest and made a comment about it in test notes. Unfortunately, our submission was rejected:

> Your add-in is not working in the following:  • Word 2013 client on
>   Windows 7  • Excel 2013 client on Windows 7 (Note: The add-in
>   framework uses Internet Explorer 11 to run the add-in) If you do not
>   support 2013 SP1 because you are using an API only available in
>   2016/Online, you must put these apis in the requirements tag in your
>   manifest.

We are in a deadlock now. It seems there is no way to meet those requirements. We sent an e-mail to Office Validation Team asking for clarification, but haven't heard back from them yet.

How do we specify that the add-in works in Office 2016 (Windows/Mac) and Office 365, but not available in Office 2013? Our App ID is 42949677685.

Comment: I'll see if I can find some help for you internally in Microsoft.

Comment: As I understand it, you are in touch with Microsoft about this issue directly. Please delete this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a policy in the Microsoft app store and the OP is in touch with Microsoft about it directly.